# Change colour of unselected Checkbox with Material UI?

Tags: material-ui

The Checkbox component accepts a `color` props which changes it's appearance when selected, but not when it's unselected. 
https://material-ui.com/api/checkbox/

```
    <Checkbox color="default" />
    <Checkbox color="primary" />
    <Checkbox color="secondary" />
```

[image]
[image]

How can I change the unselected icon's color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supply alternative icons, and then use the htmlColor property.

```
import CheckBoxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckBox';
import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckBoxOutlineBlank';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
```

...

```
<Checkbox                                  
  icon={<CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon  htmlColor="black" />}
  checkedIcon={<CheckBoxIcon htmlColor="black" />}  
/>
```